# Django Integrity error _id may not be null, ForeignKey id assignment

Tags: python, django

I'm having issues understanding the way Django (v1.6.5) assigns the id to the different objects when saving. Taking the minimal example:

```
#models.py

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Page(models.Model):
    number = models.SmallIntegerField()
    book   = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

The following view throws "IntegrityError,book_id may not be NULL" when saving my_page, however I would tend to say book_id does exist since save() has been called for the book at that stage.

```
#view.py

my_book = Book(title="My book")

#solution1 : having my_book.save() here

my_page = Page(number = 1, book = my_book)
my_book.save()
print("book id",my_page.book.id) #book.id does exist at that point!

#solution2: my_page.book = my_book

my_page.save()   #throws the IntegrityError exception
```

There are some easy solutions to make the code above work but I would like to know what is wrong with the first approach. Am I missing something or is it a glitch/limitation in the way Django handles ForeignKeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your point, but the current behavior seems more explicit. `my_book` is just a Python object, and all of its attributes (including `id`) can change. So it seems safer to assume that the user wants the value that exists at instantiation time.

For example, the Django [idiom for copying a database row](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances) involves reusing the same object to represent more than one model instance. In your case that might look like:

```
my_book = Book(title="My book")
my_page = Page(number=1, book=my_book)
my_book.save()

my_book.id = None
my_book.save()  # copy the book to a new row with a new id

my_page.save()
```

So which book should `my_page` point to? I think the developers are right to require you to be explicit here. The solution to [the associated ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10811) will be even more direct in that you will get a `ValueError` when trying to instantiate `my_page` if `my_book` hasn't yet been saved.

Answer (score 3):

You should save the book before setting `my_page.book = book`.

The behaviour you're experiencing is described by [ticket 10811](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10811).

Comment: Note that after the ticket is resolved you will still have to save the book before assigning it to the page. The solution that is proposed is to raise a `ValueError` at assignment time rather than waiting for the `save()`.

Comment: Good point @KevinChristopherHenry, I updated my answer to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `foreign key` in a model then you need to give the whole `object` in order to store a record in it. For instance if you want to save a number with book in `Page model`, so you need to give `book foreign key a book object` just because its not a normal field but its a `foreign key to the book model.`
 It can be done like following

> `my_page = Page(title="my title", book=Book.objects.get(pk=id))`

So coming to conclusion you cannot insert a record simply by giving strings to the foreign keys, you must give that `object to which foreign key is pointing`. Hope that helps

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue. Where did `id` come from? You only know the id once you've done a `save()`, and at that point you're better off pointing to your saved `my_book` rather than doing a needless trip to the database with `get()`.

Comment: In my example, I'm passing to the Page constructor a proper Book object: my_book.
To be able to initiate my_page as you're suggesting, the book has to be saved in the db beforehand which would correspond to my solution1. This does not explain why my initial approach is not working.